# Trouble printing each line of a string inside a double for loop python

Tags: python, string, loops, output

So I am working on my first terminal game in python as practice and I just can't get the output in the terminal to follow what I want.

Instance Variables:

```
board = []
board_size = 10
alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJ"
```

Code snippet:

```
def create_board():
    for i in range(0, board_size):
        board.append(["."] * board_size)
        print_board(board)

def print_board(board):
    count = 0
    while count < 10:
        for i in board:
            board_layout = alphabet[count] + "  " + " ".join(i)
            continue
        count += 1
    print(board_layout)

def main():
    create_board()
```

Terminal Output:

```
J  . . . . . . . . . .
J  . . . . . . . . . .
J  . . . . . . . . . .
J  . . . . . . . . . .
J  . . . . . . . . . .
J  . . . . . . . . . .
J  . . . . . . . . . .
J  . . . . . . . . . .
J  . . . . . . . . . .
J  . . . . . . . . . .
J  . . . . . . . . . .
```

The desired output should be A - J and with the dots at each letter.
Please let me know what I should try.

Other attemps I've tried:

```
for letter in alphabet:
        for i in board:
            board_layout = letter + "  " + " ".join(i)
            continue
    print(board_layout)

for j in range(len(alphabet)):
        for i in board:
            board_layout = alphabet[j] + "  " + " ".join(i)
    print(board_layout)
```

I've also tried switching the order of the for loops with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about doing it this way:-

```
BS = 10
ALPHA = 'ABCDEFGHIJ'
A = [[c]+['.' for _ in range(BS)] for c in ALPHA]
A.append([' ']+[x for x in range(BS)])

for r in A:
    print(*r)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, your answer immediately fixed my issue. If I may ask, what was I doing wrong?

Comment: You were just making it more complicated than it really is. The key difference between my answer and the others is that **A** is now a 2d array that you can modify as necessary during the play of your game

Comment: I feel like that's my habit since I started programming. I'm still trying to get the hang of python. But I won't stop trying until I can do it well. Thanks again man.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that. It's pretty awesome as it makes my whole project that much simpler. If you don't mind me asking, how can I go about adding numbers at the bottom of each column? I'm assuming I can just add another list at the end with only numbers in each index.

Comment: See my edited answer. Note that it will only look right if you're using a fixed width font

Comment: alternatively: `print(' ', *range(BS))` :-)

Comment: @rv.kvetch Your suggestion prints the numbers but doesn't add them to the list which is what I think was needed (I may be wrong)

Comment: yep, you are totally right. to append to the list, `A.append([' ', *range(BS)])` also works.

Comment: You guys are legendary, thanks for the assist. Both of your answers are very helpful. Initially I was trying to keep the A - J and 1 - 10 separate from the actual list, but both ways are completely doable as I'll just adjust my if statements for the attack placement method

Answer (score 1):

Try this out (short and simple):

```py
board_size = 10
alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJ"


dots = ' .' * board_size

for a in alphabet:
    print(f'{a} {dots}')
```

Explanation: when you multiply a string by a number, that string is repeated that amount of times. So `'a' * 3` becomes `'aaa'` for example.

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation, I appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
>>> BS = 10
>>> ALPHA = 'ABCDEFGHIJ'
>>> print(*[c + ' .'*BS for c in ALPHA], sep='\n')
A . . . . . . . . . .
B . . . . . . . . . .
C . . . . . . . . . .
D . . . . . . . . . .
E . . . . . . . . . .
F . . . . . . . . . .
G . . . . . . . . . .
H . . . . . . . . . .
I . . . . . . . . . .
J . . . . . . . . . .
```

Comment: This is nice and compact, although in my use case I want to be able to reprint the board out multiple times after each move by the player. Although I'll remember your syntax for future use. Your list comprehension skills are awesome.

Comment: @BassonKoch welcome dude, if you give me example  I can help  you, I can't understand this : `although in my use case I want to be able to reprint the board out multiple times after each move by the player`